# Asp.net Grid View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, view, grid

How can i retrieve NULL Field [ Date Out ]in sql 2005 database to a Grid View in ASP.Net.
I need this field to be edited by the user.

Comment: Please expand on what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the ASP.NET GridView supports binding to nullable datetime fields, however in one of the projects I develop currently I use Telerik grid with its built-in GridDateTimeColumn which supports binding to nullable datetime out-of-the-box. If you are interested take a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx) on the Telerik site.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your datatable or list, and manually set all the null values to empty string, this should work.